# WPF - Updating the existing ROW values instead of a new Row in DataGrid using ObserableCollections

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, observablecollection

I'm new to WPF and I'm trying to learn the basic things to build a simple tool for a time saving purpose. Here I'm trying to read a remote file to get the status and updating the datagrid with machine name and status of the file.

Below is the CS code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<User> users = new ObservableCollection<User>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lbUsers.ItemsSource = users;
    }

    private void btnCheckStatus_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var fileStream_status = new FileStream(@"\\LBSTR\c$\temp\range.dat", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream_status, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line.Equals("A"))
                {
                    users.Add(new User() { MachineName = "LBSTR", Status = "Close" });
                }
                else if (line.Contains("B"))
                {
                    users.Add(new User() { MachineName = "LBSTR", Status = "Open" });
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public class User 
{
    public string MachineName {set;get;}
    public string Status {set;get;}
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <DockPanel Margin="10">
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="10,0,0,0">
            <Button Name="btnCheckStatus" Click="btnCheckStatus_Click">Check Status</Button>
         
        </StackPanel>
        <DataGrid Name="lbUsers" ></DataGrid>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

When I run first time by clicking the Check Status,  a Row is getting added  with machine name and status of the file.
[For a first click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayUWb.jpg)

For the 2nd and further click the same button, a new row is getting added for the same machine.

[Further Check status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmjSy.jpg)

I just want to know how can I update the status alone to the corresponding machine name since this method is creating a new row every time when I checking the status of the file in remote machine.?  Please let me know if there is a way  or online article that helps me to identify the solution.

Comment: What have you tried so far? I don't see anything in your code to try to find and update an existing row - it's just calling Add every time.

Comment: So you have already described in your question what you need to do - find, in your `ObservableCollection` if the item you are trying to update exists, and if so, change the status of that item. Now it's a matter of coding it. So, instead of `users.Add()`, first check if `users` has the item in question, and if so, simply update it instead of adding to the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as Sach said, modify your btnCheckStatus_Click to something like this:

```
    private void BtnCheckStatus_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var fileStreamStatus = new FileStream(@"\\LBSTR\c$\temp\range.dat", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStreamStatus, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                var user = new User { MachineName = "LBSTR" };

                if (line.Equals("A"))
                    user.Status = "Close";

                else if (line.Contains("B"))
                    user.Status = "Open";

                var existingUser = _users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.MachineName.Equals(user.MachineName));

                if (existingUser != null)
                {
                    existingUser.Status = user.Status;
                    return;
                }

                _users.Add(user);
            }
        }
    }
```

Note that this line:

```
var existingUser = _users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.MachineName.Equals(user.MachineName));
```

is O(n) complex. So if you had to execute that very often - you should consider some hashed collection instead of simple ObservableCollection.

And also for DataGridCell could update the value - your User class should implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface like this:

```
public class User : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _machineName;
    private string _status;

    public string MachineName
    {
        set
        {
            if (!value.Equals(_machineName))
            {
                _machineName = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        get { return _machineName; }
    }

    public string Status
    {
        set
        {
            if (!value.Equals(_status))
            {
                _status = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        get { return _status; }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Taras for your help on this. It worked well. If you don't mind could please tell me how can I add a color to the Status column like if it is Open then Green and if it is Close then Red? I searched and most of the examples are with the help of XAML (DataGridTextColumn), but here the column already created with the help of User class.

Comment: Glag that it helped you, don't forget to mark the answer as accepted. I could help you with your further problem but as it is not related to this topic I should not post the code here. You basically need some sort of StatusToBrushConverter (which implements IValueConverter) to convert your string value to a brush and a very simple DataGridCell style with just one setter for background property bound to your Status prop using that converter.

Comment: Thanks Taras. I figured it out. I wish I could UpVote more than once but I could't Since I don't have reputations to honor you. Any how thanks for your help on this.

Comment: Well, you didn't even once, just accept the answer (click below the score)